# how to select multiple consecutive files in icon view in finder?

Tags: finder

in Windows it is easy, just shift + click, but in Mac I cannot do the same trick. I am fed up with cmd + click every single file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no exact equivalent that I'm aware of; I usually rubberband-select a region and then command-click the ones I don't want.

Mouse down at the top left of the area you want to select, drag to the bottom right of the area, release.  A rubberband will be highlighted as you drag the mouse; all icons within the rubberband will be selected.  It's also possible to chain these by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Option</kbd> for the second and successive selections, so you can add additional selections or deselect icons selected previously.